# Is it possible to integrate functions with more than 3 variables?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I can't find any material describing integration for functions with more than 3 variables, like for finding a hypervolume in a multidimensional space.

Is it possible and has been done?

In the case of a hypervolume created by the intersection of multiple hypersurfaces, it would be impossible to visualize the region, so how would we define the boundaries of integration?

What would be possible applications?

Some references for reading would be appreaciated.

Comment: Sure. What you do in 2 and dimensions generalises directly to any number of dimensions. For an application, have a look at  the Wikipedia article on the [volume of an $n$-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Direct_integration_in_spherical_coordinates). Or try it yourself for the volume of an $n$-cube. You get the bounds from the definition of the volume you are integrating over.

Comment: One example is if you wanted to say, calculate the total amount of salt in a non-homogeneously mixed volume $M=\int\int\int c(x, y, z) dx dy dz$

Comment: @eschavez thats an integral of 3 variables though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. There are many applications of four dimensional integral in Quantum Field Theory. In fact some of the research I'm currently doing has to do with integral of momenta in a toy model of Chiral Perturbation Thoery. Here is an example:

$$I_2=\int\frac{d{p^d}}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{1}{p^2+m_\sigma^2}\frac{1}{(p-q)^2+m_\pi^2} $$

This is a $d$ dimensional integral that is taken from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of a d-dimensional momenta, and represents a vertex in a Feynman diagram. Once we are done calculating the integral, we basically plug in $d=4$ as we only cary about $4-$momenta in real life.